# echo mysql column based on other column name with php

Tags: php, mysql

First of I will say I apologize for my title. I don't really know what the correct names of the mysql tables are. So I have a mysql table that looks like the following.

```
'id'  | 'username' | 'password' | 'product' | 'price'
'1'   | 'ben'      | 'hashedpw' | 'desktop' | '120'
'2'   | 'steve'    | 'hashedpw' | 'laptop'  | '300'
```

Lets say my database is named **hardware** and my user for the database is called **owner** the password is called **password** and the table is called **tech**

How would I be able to use PHP to echo the product prices.

```
$sql = "select * from users";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );

$row['prodyct'];
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to get the result to show the price of desktop only. I can't use ID since some ID's will be missing at different times.

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT price FROM tech WHERE product = 'desktop';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
$sql = "select * from users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['product'];
}
```

If you want to query for a specific product or something else use on or multiple `WHERE` conditions:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE product LIKE 'desktop'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from users";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query , MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row[product].':'.$row[price];
}
```

Please,avoid to use mysql_* functions.